# Rails has_many :through association access linking record values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models linked via a many-to-many association through a third one. The models are the following :

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :taggings
 has_many :cards, through: :taggings, inverse_of: :tags
end

class Card < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :taggings
 has_many :tags, through: :taggings, inverse_of: :cards
end

class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :card
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

I need to generate something like that in my _card.json.jbuilder partial :

```
json.tags(card.tags) do |t|
  json.id t.id
  json.name t.name
  json.tagging_id ?
  json.tagging_created_at ?
end
```

I don't want to use another request like

```
json.tagging_id = Tagging.find_by(card_id: card.id, tag_id: t.id).id
```

because I assume this would deteriorate the performance, making the request longer.

My question is : how to access the attributes of the record linking this card to this tag via the association, if it is possible ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `includes` method as already answered for eager load, so if you access any attribute through the relationship without doing additional requests to db. Also, you can use `delegate` on your model. So, for example, on your model card:

```
delegate :attribute_name, to: :tagging, prefix: :tagging
```

This way, you can access your attribute on a card_object:

```
card_object.tagging_attribute_name
```

The prefix is optional, to avoid ambiguous attributes names.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is a good solution. However, I realized that my problem was more simple than I thought, and I solved it in an easier way (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41003180/6245540). Yours would have solved my problem too so I accept it for other people to see this more universal one instead of mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually want to display in json all tagging pairs of a card?

Maybe that can help:

```
json.tags(card.taggings.includes(:tag)) do |t|
  json.id t.tag_id
  json.name t.tag.name
  json.tagging_id t.id
  json.tagging_created_at t.created_at
end
```

includes(:tag) will fetch all tags in one request, so it won't affect the performance.

Comment: Turning around your answer (which was great but I didn't express my needs well), I found the solution. I will post it in a few minutes. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution to my problem :

```
json.tags(card.taggings) do |t|
  json.id t.tag.id
  json.name t.tag.name
  json.tagging_id t.id
  json.tagging_created_at t.created_at
end
```

I was overthinking it !